# Is there any benefit to storing similar variables in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have 2 classes, a Point, which represents a point in 2D space, and a Triangle, which contains 3 Points in a list (vector) of vertices.

For an assignment, I had to write a perimeter function that gives me the perimeter of a Triangle. To do that, I need to find the 3 side lengths from the vertices, then just add them. I ended up with:

```
double Triangle::getPerimeter() {
    double s1Length = vertices[0].distanceTo(vertices[1]);
    double s2Length = vertices[1].distanceTo(vertices[2]);
    double s3Length = vertices[2].distanceTo(vertices[0]);
    return s1length + s2length + s3length;
}
```

To me though, that looked ugly, so I decided to try storing the sides in an array:

```
double Triangle::getPerimeter() {
    double lengths[3] = {
        vertices[0].distanceTo(vertices[1]),
        vertices[1].distanceTo(vertices[2]),
        vertices[2].distanceTo(vertices[0])
    }
    return lengths[0] + lengths[1] + lengths[2];
}
```

Which I subjectively see as neater.

Obviously, if this algorithm were reusable, storing the sides in a traversable has the benefit of being scalable, but this method only works for triangles; beyond that, the order of the vertices matter, and it gets more complicated.

Is it ever general practice to store variables like this in an array, for the purpose of aesthetics?

And is there any benefit beyond aesthetics? Does storing similarly used variables together in memory net any performance gains?

Comment: Why do you need to store them at all?

Comment: I certainly don't think your "arrayed" solution is neater. Personally i wouldn't even use any variables in this case, but just do `return vertices[0].distanceTo(vertices[1]) +        vertices[1].distanceTo(vertices[2]) +
        vertices[2].distanceTo(vertices[0])`

Comment: Try looking at the generated assembly. It may even be the same.

Comment: I thought having intermediates would help comprehension. I guess I could just format the return statement to help that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see why you need to store them in either many variables or array:

```
double Triangle::getPerimeter() {
    double perm = 0.0;
    for( int i =0; i < 3; ++i ) {
       int next = (i + 1) % 3;
       perm += vertices[i].distanceTo( vertices[next] );
    }
    return perm;
}
```

Anyway your code should be readable and then optimize if necessary

Comment: Here's a neater code for next index: `next = (i + 1) % 3;`

Comment: I think this is getting complicated for the simple task. If it was scalable, ya, I'd implement it with something along the lines of this. I find the less readable than `popovitsj`'s comment though, and is longer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I usually try to avoid copy/paste even when there are only 3 values. It is much easier to make a mistake with duplicate code.

Comment: @Slava So you would actually use an algorithm like this given my situation? Wouldn't it be easier to fudge some logic than to mess-up replacing a few numbers? I'm not trying to be argumentative, I'm just trying to see it from the same perspective.

Comment: @Carcigenicate based by experience yes I would prefer use algorithm. Again it is very easy to make mistake with copy/paste code. Worst thing on debuging you would look directly into mistake and not see it. Been there done that. If you care on optimization compiler should unroll the loop if necessary.

Comment: I think `for( int i = 0, j = 2; i < 3; j = i++ ) perm += vertices[i].distanceTo( vertices[j] );` is neater still. In general if something special needs to happen one time in a loop (in this case wrapping around to the beginning of the triangle), it is easier to get it out of the way in the first iteration. I also think it is nicer to keep the iteration logic within the `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, arrays (if a element is getting accessed directly without iteration) and variables have the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think If you do not need to store variables then you do not need to create three double variables or an array of double with size 3(at the end of the scope they will be deleted). I prefer to return the result without assigning the steps of solution into the variables